# Remove <xmp> tag from xml

Tags: php, xml

I would like to remove the XMP tags from "my-feed". It's a feed from Shopify and I can't change content-type to xml in Shopify. It puts out (xmp) and (/xmp) around the xml.

I've tried different approaches, but I can't figure out if it's my regular expression thats wrong or if it's not doable.

```
<? 
$url = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/myfeed');
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/feeds/mynewfeed.xml","wb");

$url = preg_replace('/<\xmp[^>]+\/>', '', $url);

fwrite($fp,$url);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Source code:

```
<xmp><?xml version="1.0"?>
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<product>
  <category>Kjole</category>
<area>0</area>
...
</xmp>
```

Comment: We have no idea what the source looks like so it would result in guessing what you are doing wrong. In general parsing xml with regex is scuky to begin with.

Comment: Source code added. I also changed preg_replace('/<\xmp[^>]+\/>', '', $url); to $url = preg_replace('/<\xmp[^>]+\/>', '', $url);. Now the regex removes to much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
<? 
$url = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/myfeed');
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/feeds/mynewfeed.xml","wb");

preg_replace('/<xmp>|<\/xmp>/', '', $url);

fwrite($fp,$url);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Like all code that attempts to process XML using regular expressions, it's wrong of course. For example, it will fail to detect xmp elements if the tag contains whitespace, and it will detect them incorrectly if they appear in CDATA sections. But perhaps it's good enough - depends on your quality requirements.